# parameter passing in imagej macro

Tags: macros, imagej

I turn to you all after many hours and visiting lots of websites and tutorials.  I need to apply a radial polynomial function to a circular roi.  The parameters for the polynomial are calculated for each image elsewhere in my imagej macro.

I have tried process>math>macro and the plugin "Expression" by Ditmer, but I cannot get the syntax correct to pass the variables. Clearly, I am not finding something about passing parameters, despite using & and even full concatenation.  In particular, I cannot find an example of Expression being used in macro mode to get the syntax of its arguments.

Here is a sample of code that runs on a single open image:

```
run("32-bit");
rename("working");
//setTool("oval");
makeOval(30, 37, 444, 444);
p0=1.31061     
p1=-0.0023456;
p2=-0.000017459;
selectWindow("working");
//run("Macro...", "code=v=v*(1.31061-0.0023456*d-0.00001745*pow(d,2))");
//run("Macro...", "code=v=v*(&p0+&p1*d+&p2*pow(d,2))");
//run("Expression ", "preset='Radial_cutdown'");
//run("Expression ", "preset='Radial_cutdown_parampass'");
```

The first run command works.  The second does not.

The third uses Ditmer's Expression plugin with the preset code as follows:

```
i*(1.31061-0.0023456*d-0.00001745*d*d)
0
0
0
maxval
0
0
0
w
h
0
100
```

This also works.  However a preset containing the macro parameters instead of numbers does not:

```
Radial_cutdown_parampass
i*(&p0+&p1*d+&p2*d*d)
0
0
0
maxval
0
0
0
w
h
0
100
```

I apologize for asking what should be a simple question, but I admit to being stumped.

Comment: If you've spent hours searching, I'm sure you also have come across the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html), which is usually the best place to ask and also to report bugs (since if something doesn't work as you expect it to work from tutorials, that might also be a bug..).

Answer (score 1):

Use [String concatenation](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html#run) syntax:

```
run("Macro...", "code=v=v*(" + p0 + "+" + p1 + "*d+" + p2 + "*pow(d,2))");
```